# Accessing values in promise

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have this code in my controller used to create an `Item`:

```
Item.create(short).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

and this is an extract from a corresponding service which returns a `promise`:

```
return sync.$set({title: "test", random: "random string created in this service"});
```

I want to now use the `random` string that was created in my controller. I'm getting the response but I'm not sure how I can access the data.

I've tried `response.random` `response.data.random` etc but everything I try is `undefinded`

Comment: How does it look like when you are logging response?

Comment: `E {m: De, path: F, Ca: undefined, da: undefined, wa: undefined…}` There are more layers in it too which I don't understand.

Comment: What you have look slike a Firebase `DataSnapshot`. To get the value from it, you do `response.val()`.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I will give that a try. You seem to answer all my questions on Firebase - feel free to offer them as "answers"

Comment: However, this doesn't work. I get `undefined is not a function` in the console

Comment: @tommy if the function is undefined, then it will be up to you to explore this and add some appropriate details to your question. All anyone can do is guess until you provide an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kato: you're trying to get tommy to use the awesome new Stack Snippets/Code snippets editor, aren't you? Admit it!

Answer (score 0):

You code sample is pretty slim (1 line of code from your service?) and your troubleshooting details are also a bit terse. Please provide as much data as possible to help us formulate a complete picture.

Making some assumptions here from what is available, and reading [the documentation on AngularFire's $set method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-set-key-data), we can come up with the following:

- $set returns a promise which resolves to **a firebase reference** (not the data you sent; not a snapshot)
- you want to receive the random id (or possible the json data you sent)
- there are probably better designs we could utilize with a more complete picture of your use case

Here's a quick idea of how to resolve this, by chaining the promises and returning whatever you would like, instead of the not-as-useful ref:

```
var randomId = /* some magic */;
var data = {title: "test", random: randomId};
return sync.$set(data).then(function(ref) {
   return sync; // we could also return data here, sync seems the most flexible
});
```

Now we can do the following:

```
Item.create(short).then(function(item){
  console.log(item.random);
}/*, function(error) {} */);
```